# neo4j 2.0 Failed to mark transaction as rollback only

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

I am building a stand-alone java application, and using neo4j in embedded mode with Cypher for storing the information. I have built this function, for general purposes:

```
private ExecutionResult runCypher(String query)
{
    Transaction tx = service.beginTx();
    ExecutionResult result = null;
    boolean success = true;

    try
    {
        result = engine.execute(query);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        success = false;
    }
    finally
    {
        if(success) tx.success();
        else        tx.failure();
    }

    tx.close();

    return result;
}
```

The problem is i constantly get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.neo4j.graphdb.TransactionFailureException: Failed to    mark transaction as rollback only.
at org.neo4j.kernel.TopLevelTransaction.markAsRollbackOnly(TopLevelTransaction.java:97)
at org.neo4j.kernel.TopLevelTransaction.failure(TopLevelTransaction.java:86)
```

If i modify the finally clause, and always go for tx.failure(), there are no problems. What's going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would change the code to:

```
private ExecutionResult runCypher(String query, Map params) {
    try (Transaction tx = service.beginTx()) {
        ExecutionResult result = engine.execute(query, params);
        // extract the data out of the result, you cannot iterate over it outside of a tx
        Collection resultData = ....
        tx.success();
        return resultData;
    }
}
```

1. you have to iterate and extract data from the ExecutionResult within a transaction
2. Transactions support the try-with pattern
3. You still have to call `tx.success()`
4. `tx.failure()` will be automatically assumed if you haven't called `tx.success()`
5. **And always use parameters.**

Comment: Yes, i did not expect this, but it is logical; another transaction might start while i process the ExecutionResult, which is a reference. Then i might get new values in the object. Is this correct? The no 5 tip is great, thank you for that!